# In how many ways in the set {1,2,..,n} the element $k$ is greater than all the numbers on its left?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways in the set {1,2,..,$n$} the element $k$ is greater than
> all the numbers on its left?
>
> Example: $k=4$ $n=5$, 23415 is legal, 54312 is illegal

My attemp: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{k-i}{1}\left ( k-i-1 \right )!$

$\binom{k-i}{1}$ possible ways to find a place for $k$ such that its index can't be greater than $k$
and depending on it's current index there is $\left ( k-i-1 \right )!$ numbers left to arrange that can be smaller than $k$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: So the numbers are $1, 2.. k...n$ occur only once with no repetition?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, basically it's a sequence increasing by 1 from 1 to n

Comment: OK then you have some mistakes. First of all your permutation for the left do not seem right. Also note that the values on the right will have permutations that will give also different arrangements.

Comment: @MathLover yes I forgot about the permutations on the right, but why the permutations for the left doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 3):

By ignoring all elements other than $k$ and larger, we see that your original sequences will satisfy the property iff $k$ is the smallest of these.  The probability of this happening is $\dfrac{1}{n-k+1}$ so the total number of such sequences (*including those elements smaller*) is then $$\frac{n!}{n-k+1}$$

Alternatively, if you dislike using a probabilistic argument in this, approach by first picking the positions of the elements $k$ and greater.  The first of those must be occupied by $k$ but the remaining can be in any order.  Finally, those elements smaller than $k$ can be in any order in what remains, giving:

$$\binom{n}{n-k+1}(n-k)!(k-1)!$$

which of course simplifies again to the above.

Comment: i upvoted. i regard both parts of your answer as elegant.

Comment: +1 If I was doing, I would have done the 2nd way. But now that I see it, the probabilistic argument is great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to think for each position from the left then here is how it will look -

Say $k$ is at the first place (from the left). You can permute the left of it in $^{(k-1)}P_0$ ways. You have to basically choose and arrange all the numbers lower than $k$ to its left. To the right you can permute it in (n-1)!.

Say $k$ is at the 2nd place. You can permute the left in $^{(k-1)}P_1$ ways and the right in $(n-2)!$ ways.

For $k$ in $i$ position, left to $k$ will be $^{(k-1)}P_{(i-1)}$ permutations and to the right it will be (n-i)!

So, $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} {^{(k-1)}P_{(i-1)}} (n-i)!$ is what you are looking for.